# JQuery validate confirm invalidhandler is being set

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Hi does anyone know how to ensure the invalidhandler is set with jquery validate?

It does not seem to be running even though I've tried to set it.

I can get the validator via:

```
var validator = $("form_selector").data("validator");
```

This has an invalid property on it but I can't find an invalidHandler.

Can someone please tell me how to work out what the invalid handler is set to . I thought it would just be:

```
validator.invalidHandler
```

But it did not work.

Comment: You've shown us zero relevant code.  Where is the HTML markup of the form and the call to `.validate()`?  Did you also include the plugin?

Comment: @Sparky what's irrelevent about that code. I'm showing you how I get the validator and I want to know how to see what the invalidHandler is set to. This should make perfect sense to anyone familiar with Jquery validate. It doesn't matter about how or where it was set I merely want to check what it is set to for debugging purposes.

Comment: *"should make perfect sense to anyone familiar with Jquery validate"* ~  I've answered [more than 1500 questions about this plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/topusers). It matters how or where it was set because we'd use your own code to construct a working demo. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: *"It (`invalidHandler`) does not seem to be running even though I've tried to set it."*. ~ This is really the root issue, right?  We can't help if we can't see the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `console.log(validator)` to inspect your `validator` object.

Viewing how this object is constructed, you would then see `invalidHandler` located under `settings`.

```
validator.settings.invalidHandler
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/hc244fr8/](http://jsfiddle.net/hc244fr8/)**

Comment: yep that is what I was after. Was not aware it was under settings.